# Saving image to SD card not working

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Having a problem at the bottom, I'm trying to create a case to save the image to SD card yet it isn't working and I don't know why.
I think it's got something to do with the getRawResource but still not sure.

Thanks for any help!!!

```
    package com.nk_apps.random;

import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Main extends Activity {

    private Gallery gallery;
    private ImageView imgView;

    private Integer[] imgId = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView01);    
        imgView.setImageResource(imgId[0]);

         gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
         gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

         gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                imgView.setImageResource(imgId[position]); 
            }
        });

    }

    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
            cont = c;
            TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            typArray.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return imgId.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

            imgView.setImageResource(imgId[position]);
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(170, 270));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

            return imgView;}

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bsaveImage:
                InputStream inps = getResources().openRawResource(GalItemBg);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inps);
                try{
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, "Title" , "Hip-Hop Wallpapers");
                    Toast saveToast = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "The image has been saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    saveToast.show();
                }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

} }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Please add details about the error to your question. What happens exactly and what should happen?

Comment: Can you provide `logcat` output?

Comment: It's the switch at the end which should save the image. So far it does nothing. For some reason a logcat could not be filed, must be because I'm on a nightly TouchWiz Jellybean ROM. Although, even when saving something to the SD with the emulator it should force close yet nothing is happening on either.

Answer (score 2):

Did you verify you have write permission to sdcard ? (this is WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Also, you should make sure you look at the right mount point to find the image (can be "internal sdcard" for some devices, for example).

Comment: Then did you check what insertImage() returns ? It's supposed to give you an URL, if it actually saved something to an unexpected place you'll get the information. If you get null, then you definitely need to get logcat...

Comment: The button is to save images from the res/ folder, not from a URL.